# Find and replace HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a Bookmarklet or Browser extension that will modify another website when I view it, more specifically I am trying to use a Javascript Markdown editor with button bar like Stackexchange uses on another website that I do not own so I must do it with a bookmarklet or extension.

Right now I need to find the textarea on a page and replace it with a different block of code like below.  The page does have jQuery so I can use that... IF you can show me how to do this I would really appreciate it, thanks

Find

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="description" id="description" tabindex="4"></textarea>
```

Replace with...

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
    <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" name="description"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. we just need to simply replace the HTML, like so:

```
var htmlToReplace = ' \
  <div class="wmd-panel"> \
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div> \
      <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" name="description"></textarea> \
  </div> \
  <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>';

$("#description").replaceWith(htmlToReplace)
```

And that'll do the trick for you.

Comment: Looks great, maybe you can help some with the bigger question that will use this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544597/include-external-javascript-and-css-files-into-another-sites-dom thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out .replaceWith()

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

```
$("#description").replaceWith('ALL YOUR CODE');
```

You can use more [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if you need to match attributes or other characteristics